# How do I make a plane have a colored material in Cycles while adding thickness?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders

How do I make a plane have a colored material in cycles render mode, while making it at the same time have thickness?

Comment: `I need to make a little rise out of a cube.` That is confusing me :/ The other part makes sense, have a plane, add a material, and a *Solidify* modifier

Comment: perfect all i needed, i appreciate it

Comment: whatha??????....

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise could you put that as an answer (strange as it may seem) so we can get this off the kill list?

Comment: @VinceScalia Done. **Luke Taylor** (and everyone else), it is common courtesy to give someone who answered in the comments at *least* 12hrs to post as an answer, as there are many different time zones. I was asleep when the comment showing this was an answer was posted.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev If my answer helped, please accept it

Answer (score 4):

This can be done very easily thanks to the Cycles material editor and the *Solidify* modifier.

First add a material and change the color as desired. The default material is a light grey diffuse material:

[image: AddMaterial]

Then add the *Solidify* modifier and change the *Thickness* value:

[image: Solidify Material]

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... A material for color. You need a plane for the square, and you can make it thicker with the solidify modifier.

Comment: Bravo! +1 for... well for doing that.

Comment: lol. I didn't know what he wanted.